# Проблема с выводом данных из словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

не могу связать самую высокую высоту и название самой высокой вершины 
Если выбрать максимальный ключ и максимальное значение как у меня в коде ниже то программа выведет не связанные между собой значения высоты,то есть у меня к примеру на входе:"а":800 "b":900 на выходе у меня должно:"Самая высокая вершина:"b=900м
код:

```
slovar = {}
n = int(input("Введите кол-во вершин:"))
for i in range(n):
    k = input("Введите названия вершини:")
    d = int(input("Введите высоту вершины:"))
    slovar[k] = d
print("Cамые высокие вершины мира:",slovar)
g = slovar.keys()
g = max(g)
print(g)
d = slovar.values()
d = max(d)
print("Cамая высокая вершина:",g,d)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выберите самую высокую вершину из заданного словаря](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922354/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f)

Comment: вопрос другой если вы читали описание проблемы

Comment: Какой логический смысл вы закладываете в поиск максимального ключа?

Comment: ну вообще для меня было открытием,что у максимального элемента по значению можно якобы найти ключ таким образом

Comment: то есть я вложил смысл,что максимальный ключ соответствует максимальному значению,но как оказалось этот ключ с максимальным значением не связаны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще словарь не как `<имя: значение>` использовать, а как `<значение: имя>`.

Пример:

```
height_by_name = dict()

n = int(input("Введите кол-во вершин: "))

for i in range(n):
    name = input("Введите названия вершини: ")
    height = int(input("Введите высоту вершины: "))
    height_by_name[height] = name

print("Cамые высокие вершины мира:", list(height_by_name.values()))

# Самая высокая вершина
max_height = max(height_by_name)

# Получаем название вершины по ее высоте
max_name = height_by_name[max_height]

text = 'Самая высокая вершина: "{} = {}м"'.format(max_name, max_height)
print(text)
```

Еще можно сразу при получении данных найти самую высокую:

```
max_height = 0
max_name = None

n = int(input("Введите кол-во вершин: "))

for i in range(n):
    name = input("Введите названия вершини: ")
    height = int(input("Введите высоту вершины: "))

    # Обновляем информацию о самой высокой вершине
    if height > max_height:
        max_height = height
        max_name = name

text = 'Самая высокая вершина: "{} = {}м"'.format(max_name, max_height)
print(text)
```

Еще вариант:

```
name_by_height = dict()

n = int(input("Введите кол-во вершин: "))
for i in range(n):
    k = input("Введите названия вершини: ")
    d = int(input("Введите высоту вершины: "))
    name_by_height[k] = d

max_height = max(name_by_height.values())

for name, height in name_by_height.items():
    # Ищем наши вершины
    if height != max_height:
        continue

    text = 'Самая высокая вершина: "{} = {}м"'.format(name, max_height)
    print(text)
```

---

**PS.**

Либо, вы можете не менять ваш `slovar`, а сделать обратный словарь после заполнения:

```
height_by_name = {v: k for k, v in slovar.items()}

max_height = max(height_by_name)
...
```

**PPS.**

Текущий алгоритм выведет только одну максимальную вершину, чтобы была поддержка нескольких вершин с одинаковой высотой, нужно чтобы в словаре значением был список названий вершин:

```
from collections import defaultdict

height_by_names = defaultdict(list)

n = int(input("Введите кол-во вершин: "))

for i in range(n):
    name = input("Введите названия вершин: ")
    height = int(input("Введите высоту вершины: "))
    height_by_names[height].append(name)

print("Cамые высокие вершины мира:", list(height_by_names.values()))

# Самая высокая вершина
max_height = max(height_by_names)
max_names = height_by_names[max_height]

for name in max_names:
    text = 'Самая высокая вершина: "{} = {}м"'.format(name, max_height)
    print(text)
```

Comment: а каким ещё способом можно получить самые высокие вершины?

Comment: @Noob_Prog В цикле `for i in range(n):` проверять значение самой большой вершины и запоминать ее высоту и название

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример как вторым способом,у меня пока не получается

Comment: @Noob_Prog, добавил

Comment: вы меня не поняли,я говорю каким способом можно получить самые высокие вершины когда несколько одинаковых самых высоких высот кроме использования defaultdict(list)?

Comment: `кроме использования defaultdict(list)` тогда используйте просто словарь с списком внутри -- сам список добавляйте если значения (т.е. списка)  по тому ключу нет. Либо храните в словаре `<название>: <высота>`, после находите максимальную высоту и в цикле перебираете элементы с таким значением

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87234/discussion-between-noob-prog-and-gil9red).

Answer (score 1):

Начнём с простого примера и будем постепенно усложнять

```
In [1]: a = [3, 2, 1]

In [2]: b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [3]: max(a)
Out[3]: 3

In [4]: max(b)
Out[4]: 'c'
```

Логично, что максимальное значение в одном списке никак не влияет на максимальное значение другого.

```
In [5]: d = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}

In [6]: d.keys()
Out[6]: dict_keys(['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [7]: d.values()
Out[7]: dict_values([3, 2, 1])
```

Видно, что методы словаря `keys` и `values` возвращают разные списки.

```
In [8]: max(d.keys())
Out[8]: 'c'

In [9]: max(d.values())
Out[9]: 3
```

Неразумно ожидать, что связь волшебным образом появится и один максимум вдруг станет каким-то образом зависим от другого.

Если нужно сохранить связь между ключами и значениями, то работать с ними надо как с парами значений:

```
In [10]: d.items()
Out[10]: dict_items([('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)])
```

И максимум искать по одному из значений в паре:

```
In [11]: print("Cамая высокая вершина:", *max(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
Cамая высокая вершина: c 3
```

Либо компактнее, как я вам отвечал в вашем предыдущем вопросе:

```
print("Самая высокая вершина: ", max(d, key=d.get))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mountains = {'Эльбрус': 5642, 'Мак-Кинли': 6168, 'Эверест': 8848, 'Арарат': 5165}
mountain, peak = max(mountains.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
print(mountain, peak, sep=': ')
```